# How to allow font as static files in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm currently working on a web application(ASP.NET Core, razor pages) and I have fonts on my 'www' folder since they're static files, but once the application is running it gives me a 404 error [image]

currently I have this on my Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            StaticFileOptions options = new StaticFileOptions();
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.FileExtensionContentTypeProvider typeProvider = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            if (!typeProvider.Mappings.ContainsKey(".woff2"))
            {
                typeProvider.Mappings.Add(".woff2", "application/font-woff2");
            }
            options.ContentTypeProvider = typeProvider;
            app.UseStaticFiles(options);
            //app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc();




        }
```

Comment: Are they in your `wwwroot` folder?

Comment: @John yes, it's inside the wwwroot folder

Comment: What about the _paths_ that use the fonts (css, etc.)?

Comment: @EdSF it's using the correct path.

Comment: @RandelRamirez I believe the correct mime type for .woff2 is `font/woff2`. Also, are your font files located inside some subfolder of `wwwroot` or root of `wwwroot`?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood it's inside a folder named 'fonts'

Comment: @RandelRamirez Which version of ASP.NET Core are you using? `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider` class already has .woff2 mime type mapping defined https://github.com/damianh/StaticFilesMiddleware/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles/ContentTypes/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs. Ensure that font paths are correct and are you loading them from css file?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood asp.net core 2.2, and yes they're loaded from css

Comment: @RandelRamirez So have you confirmed that font path is correct? Check using `Network` tab of Developer console.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood yes, the path is correct

Comment: An unknown mime-type will not cause a 404. It just won't be served correctly, and therefore, not interpreted by the client correctly. The 404 is only going to occur if the path is bad. The CSS likely has a relative path, you need to ensure that that path is correct relative actual location of the CSS file. Things like bundling and minification can often screw up relative path references.

Comment: @RandelRamirez Try to lower case all fonts names, that worked for me.